# use JSON object with rails scoped

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, json, parameters

I want to the following thing to happen:

When I select a selectbox I want it to send a JSON object through AJAX to my controller like so :

```
        var encoded = $.param(data);            
        jQuery.ajax ({
            url: '/trips',
            type: 'GET',
            data: {'toSearch' : encoded},
            success: function (response) {
                //succes
                console.log(encoded);
            }
        });
```

and use these as params for my query like so

```
respond_to :json, :html

  def index
    @trips = Trip.scoped
    @trips.where("category_id = ?", params[:category_ids]) if params[:category_ids] # category_ids = array; select * from trips where category_id IN [1,3,4]


    respond_with @trips
  end
```

How do I do this? and what is the best way to serialize my JSON object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
def index
  @trips = Trip.scoped
  @trips.where("category_id = ?", params[:category_ids]) if params[:category_ids] # category_ids = array; select * from trips where category_id IN [1,3,4]

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.xml  { render :xml => @trips }
    format.json { render :json => @trips }
  end
end
```

Then you should do whatever you want to in the javascript callback.

**Edit**

If you want just the json format you can do the following:

```
render :json => @trips
```

You can also check the [Layouts and Rendering in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) guide.

Comment: I do not have enough reputation to do that.